# How can I run app tests that use Google App Engine PHP SDK functions from the command line

Tags: php, google-app-engine, unit-testing

Is it possible to load the GAE PHP SDK via composer or some other method so I can run SDK functions outside of the development server? Right now I have a php app that uses some of the functions to generate image urls. The app works fine when running from a browser in the dev server or pushed into production but I can't run functional tests via the command line. Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not documented, hence not (yet) supported, there's a php_cli.py script under the SDK root that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Awesome. I forgot my testing framework uses curl so I'm still stuck but this is going to help a ton with other things.

Comment: Great. The intention is to support curl eventually so stay tuned.

Comment: Awesome++. Any plans for auto updating composer dependancies in the works? I would love to get those out of my repos.

Comment: Please star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9670